# Al intentar renderizar, no lo hace a la primera

Tags: reactjs, axios, usestate, useeffect

Como ven debajo, estoy haciendo una petición a la api de pokemon, en base al tipo que venga por url; son peticiones de aprox más de 100 resultados(objetos) en un array.
Mi problema es que no renderiza a la primera, ya realicé `console.log()` para saber si la información llega correctamente y así lo hace, pero cuando se tiene que mostrar en la pantalla tengo que por ejemplo entrar dos veces al link para poder ver los datos traídos por la petición.

Dejo el código adjunto con la petición que estoy haciendo con axios, y cómo uso State y Effect.

A su vez lo que trae cambia dependiendo del pathname del `useLocation`, lo utilicé para hacer la petición en axios dependiendo del tipo que se clickeó al ingresar a la ruta.

```
const Types = () => {

    const URLbase = 'https://pokeapi.co/api/v2';
    const { pathname } = useLocation();
    const title = pathname.slice(6);

    const [pokemon, setPokemon] = useState([]);

    useEffect(() => {

        const getPokemon = async () => {
            try {

                const list = [];
    
                const res = await axios({url:`${URLbase}${pathname}`});
                const {data} = res; 
                data.pokemon.map(async({pokemon}) => {
                    
                    try {
                        const res = await axios({url: `${pokemon.url}`}); 
                        const {data} = res;
                        list.push(data);
    
                    } catch (err) {
                        console.log(err);
                    }
                }) 
    
                return setPokemon(list);
    
            } catch (err) {
                console.log(err);
            }
        }

        getPokemon();

    }, [pathname])

    console.log(pokemon)  
    
  return (
    <main className='types'>
        <div className="routes">
            <ul>
                <li>
                    <Link to={'/'}>Home <MdChevronRight/></Link>
                </li>
                <li>
                    {title}
                </li>
            </ul>
        </div>

        <div className="content-pokemon">
            {pokemon.map(({order, name, sprites, types}) => (
                <CartPokemon key={name} order={order} name={name} sprites={sprites.other['official-artwork'].front_default ? sprites.other['official-artwork'].front_default : unknow} type={types[0].type.name}/> 
            ))}
        </div>
         
    </main>
  )
}
```

Comment: Hay que verificar lo siguiente `data.pokemon.map(async({pokemon}) ...` dentro de la función `getPokemon`, la llave `pokemon` no es parte de la estructura `data`. Hay otras llaves  que si son `arrays` como por ejemplo `abilities` o `forms`. Sugiero iniciar la depuración por ahi. saludos

Comment: data.pokemon es un array de objetos, dentro de estos objetos iterados se encuentra la prop 'url' que contiene la info de ese pokemon
Al hacer la petición con axios ```await axios({url: `${pokemon.url}`})``` nos devuelve objetos que luego guardo en la variable ```const list = []```
Y al hacer un .log de list en esta ocasión me devuelve un array de los objetos que fueron pusheados a list
Sigo sin poder resolverlo, toda ayuda es bienvenida

https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/type/normal